# Why am I getting this connection error when trying to upload an image to S3 with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, multer

I am creating a chat application and want to save different chat server images to an S3 bucket.

I have a simple form in HTML that allows me to choose save a server name, catefory and image url to mongoDB. The image should also get uploaded to my S3 bucket, but in my Node console I receive the following error:

```
Error: connect ENETUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
```

I am using multers3 and the aws-sdk.

Why do I get this error? I have looked at other examples on SO but none of the solutions help fix my issue.

**dashboard.ejs**:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/dashboard" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="server" placeholder="Server Name">
        <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="Category">

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-info" type="button" id="uploadBtn">Upload Image</button>
        <input type="file" name="upload" id="uploadInput" style="display: none">

        <button>Add Server</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**awsUpload.js**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION
});

const s0 = new AWS.S3();
const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s0,
        bucket: 'chapp-images-server',
        acl: 'public-read',
        metadata: function(req, file, cb){
            cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
        },
        key: function(req, file, cb){
            console.log(file);
            cb(null, file.originalname);
        }
    }),

    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    }
});

exports.Upload = upload;
```

**admin.js**

```
module.exports = function(formidable, Server, aws){
    return {
        setRoute: function(router){
            router.get('/dashboard', this.adminPage);

            router.post('/uploadFile', aws.Upload.any(), this.uploadFile);
            router.post('/dashboard', this.adminPostPage);
        },

        adminPage: function(req, res){
            res.render('admin/dashboard');
        },

        adminPostPage: function(req, res){
            const newClub = new Server();
            newClub.name = req.body.server;
            newClub.category = req.body.category;
            newClub.image = req.body.upload;
            newClub.save((err) => {
                res.render('admin/dashboard');
            })
        },

        uploadFile: function(req, res) {
            const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

            form.on('file', (field, file) => {

            });
            form.on('error', (err) => {

            });
            form.on('end', () => {

            });

            form.parse(req);
        }
    }
};
```

I think I have included all the relevant files, if it is easier I can upload a link to my GitHub repo.

I have already tried the following:

- Removed environment variables for my AWS accesskey and secretaccesskey and entered them in manually
- Removed `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from the form
- Changed my bucket to allow public access (in-case it was an access issue)
- Creating a new S3 bucket and using that one instead

EDIT:
**.env**:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=key
AWS_REGION=eu-west-2
export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205232/discussion-on-question-by-af-web-why-am-i-getting-this-connection-error-when-try).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by adding a `Bucket Policy` to my S3 bucket.

For other's who may have similar issues this is how I did it:

1. Click on your username in the top right and select "My Account"
2. Make a note of your `Account ID` which should be at the top of the page
3. Navigate to your S3 buckets and select the Bucket you wish to add a Bucket Policy to
4. Select the `Permissions` tab and select the `Bucket Policy` button
5. Press the `Policy generator` link which can be found underneath the bucket policy editor window
6. A new window with some options will open, fill in the following fields:

   - `Select Type of Policy: S3 Bucket Policy`
   - `Principal: arn:aws:iam::<YOURACCOUNTID>:root`
   - `Actions: Tick the "All Actions" tickbox next to it`
   - `Amazon Resource Name (ARN): Your S3 ARN which can be found in the Bucket Policy window near the top. It will look similar to this -> arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME`
7. After entering all the values you should be able to press the "Add Statement" button
8. Now press the Generate Policy" button at the bottom of the page and it should open a window containing some JSON
9. Copy this JSON and paste it into your `Bucket policy editor` textarea and press save

You should now have access to your S3 bucket.

Comment: glad it working for you. but this will make this bucket accessible by all the users of your account.